# Threading in Tkinter

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I am having a problem with threading in Tkinter. I read that things shoud be done in separate threads apart from the main GUI thread. Whenever I click the button it closes after the thread stops. I do not think I am implementing the threading correctly.

```
from Tkinter import *
from scrapy import cmdline
import thread

def scrapeMe():
    if(RadioVar.get() == 1):
        thread.start_new_thread(cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl s1".split()))
    if(RadioVar.get() == 2):
        thread.start_new_thread(cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl s2".split()))


root = Tk()

B1 = Button(root, text="Scrape", command = scrapeMe)

RadioVar = IntVar()

R1 = Radiobutton(root, text = "1", variable = RadioVar, value=1)
R2 = Radiobutton(root, text = "2", variable = RadioVar, value=2)


B1.pack()
R1.pack()
R2.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is your question? You didn't ask anything.

Comment: Program closes after clicking on the button when it should keep running. Sorry I thought that could be inferred should have added.

Comment: Ok, so the program closes. What's the question? Do you want it to close? Does it close with errors?

Comment: No errors, I would like the thread to execute and have the GUI keep running while its executing. So you click the button, and the thread starts, GUI keeps running, thread ends, GUI still running. -Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I fixed most of the problems. The first one being, you used 'threading' in a wrong way. I'm not sure on how to use scrapy, so I'll leave that to you or someone else. At the very least, I got it to run for you.

```py
from tkinter import *
from scrapy import cmdline
import threading

def scrapeMe():
    if(RadioVar.get() == 1):
        threading.Thread(cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl s1".split()))
    if(RadioVar.get() == 2):
        threading.Thread(cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl s2".split()))


root = Tk()

B1 = Button(root, text="Scrape", command = scrapeMe)

RadioVar = IntVar()

R1 = Radiobutton(root, text = "1", variable = RadioVar, value=1)
R2 = Radiobutton(root, text = "2", variable = RadioVar, value=2)


B1.pack()
R1.pack()
R2.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This could also help
https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html